# core ajax into polymer element dont do the response function

Tags: ajax, polymer, paper-elements

Dont do the response handler function, i dont know why

Outside the paper elemet, using the document.getelemetbyid(), do the respnser, but when i put it into the paper element, dont do anything.

Here is my code:

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-ajax/core-ajax.html">
<polymer-element name="post-service" attributes="posts">
<template>
    <style>
        :host {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>

    <core-ajax auto url="http://yami-no-seire.hol.es/blog/api/get_recent_posts/" on-core-response="{{postsLoaded}}" handleAs="json">
    </core-ajax>
</template>
<script>
    Polymer({
        created: function () {
            this.posts = [];
        },

        /*AJAX Success Callback Method*/
        postsLoaded: function() {
        console.log("Ok");

            var respuesta = this.$.ajax

            /*document.querySelector('#student-table-template').model = {
                posts: e.detail.response
            };*/
            var data = respuesta.detail.response.posts,
                posts = [],
                el = document.createElement("div");
            // build custom object
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                //escape title
                el.innerHTML = data[i].title;
                var title = el.innerHTML;
                //escape content
                el.innerHTML = data[i].excerpt;
                var excerpt = el.innerHTML;

                entradas.push({
                    url: data[i].url,
                    title: title,
                    excerpt: excerpt.replace('&nbsp;', ' ').replace('<p>', '').replace('</p>', ''),
                    modified: parseDate(data[i].modified),
                    name: data[i].author.name
                });
            }
            this.posts = posts;
        }
    });

    function parseDate(date) {
                var d = new Date(date);
                var months = ["January", "February", "March",
  "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
  "October", "November", "December"
];
                return d.getDate() + " - " + months[d.getMonth()] + " - " + d.getFullYear();
            };
</script>
</polymer-element>
```

It looks like the core-ajax dont handler the request.

Answer (score 0):

Automatic [node finding](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/polymer.html#automatic-node-finding)

```
this.$.ajax
```

targets elements by id attribute, which is missing in your core-ajax element:

```
<core-ajax auto url="(my url)" id='ajax'...
```

Here is working example:
[Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/hhduEb5OkoTtH8QjcQBx?p=preview)

Edit:
Here is how to catch the response inside the postsLoaded:

```
 postsLoaded: function(e, detail, sender){

    console.log('postsLoaded');
    console.log(e.detail.response);
  },
```

But if you are not getting even the 'Ok' log, then it can be wrong URL.

Comment: I put the ID, put it still doesnt show me the log OK from the response handler

Comment: I have edited my url, the url is ok, whitout the polymer element, it response correctly